# Which method should I use for determining sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, sample-size

What is the difference between the sample size determination
method of (a) using the critical values of the normal distribution and (b) that of using the t-distribution?

As an example: if replication level $a=3$, confidence Interval=95%, $\sigma^2=16.9$, maximum error of estimation $D=\pm3$, then for determining sample size we can use $n=\frac{2Z^2\sigma^2}{D^2}$ or $D=t_{\alpha/2,df}\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma^2}{n}}$.

But I can't understand which formula I should use.